# OrientDB how to store existing Java models

Tags: orientdb

I have an existing hierarchy of Java classes that represents a model in my application.
For example, I have Account<-User  Account<-Company classes.

How to store this hierarchy in OrientDB ? Is it possible to automatically create OrientDB Classes based on the existing models ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrientDB automatically manages POJO with no need to configure mapping before using it.

```
// OPEN THE DATABASE
OObjectDatabaseTx db = new OObjectDatabaseTx ("remote:localhost/petshop").open("admin", "admin");

// REGISTER THE CLASS ONLY ONCE AFTER THE DB IS OPEN/CREATED
db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClasses("foo.domain");

// CREATE A NEW PROXIED OBJECT AND FILL IT
Account account = db.newInstance(Account.class);
account.setName( "Luke" );
account.setSurname( "Skywalker" );

City rome =  db.newInstance(City.class,"Rome",  db.newInstance(Country.class,"Italy"));
account.getAddresses().add(new Address("Residence", rome, "Piazza Navona, 1"));

db.save( account );
```

For more information look at: [OrientDB Object API](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Object-Database.html).

Comment: you might also want to add the line: db.setAutomaticSchemaGeneration(true) for some cases;